# How to call a function of different activity from another activity

Tags: android

I want to call the function populateTimeList() in MainFragmentActivity2 class from the onClick function of TimePickerPopup class. How do I do so? these are the codes respectively. I am very new to android, please help!

```
public class MainActivityFragment2 extends Fragment {

private List<TimeList> TDList = new ArrayList<TimeList>();

public MainActivityFragment2() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private void populateTimeList() {
    Context ctx = this.getActivity();
    DBoperations db = new DBoperations(ctx);
    Cursor cr = db.getInformation(db);
    cr.moveToFirst();
    String TimeH, TimeM, EtimeH, EtimeM;
    do {
        TimeH = Integer.toString(cr.getInt(1));
        TimeM = Integer.toString(cr.getInt(2));
        EtimeH = Integer.toString(cr.getInt(3));
        EtimeM = Integer.toString(cr.getInt(4));
        TDList.add((new TimeList(TimeH + " : " + TimeM, EtimeH + " : " + EtimeM)));
    }while (cr.moveToNext());
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TimeList> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<TimeList> values) {

        super(context, R.layout.time_list_item,values);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        if( v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TimeList currLoc = TDList.get(position);

        TextView theTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_list_item_textview1);
        theTextView.setText(currLoc.getTime());

        theTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_list_item_textview2);
        theTextView.setText(currLoc.getDuration());

        return v;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_list_view, container, false);

    ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.time_list_view);
    final ArrayAdapter<TimeList> adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),TDList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    populateTimeList();
    setRetainInstance(true);

    ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivityFragment2.this.getActivity(), TimePickerPopup.class));
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

And

```
public class TimePickerPopup extends Activity {

private List<TimeList> TDList = new ArrayList<TimeList>();
Context ctx =this;

private TimePicker time_picker1;
private TimePicker time_picker2;
private ImageButton select_time1;
private ImageButton select_time2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.time_picker);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .7+50));

    time_picker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    time_picker2 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
    select_time1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.selectButton1);
    select_time2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.selectButton2);

    select_time1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Start time " + time_picker1.getCurrentHour() + " : " + time_picker1.getCurrentMinute(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ScrollView sv1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
            sv1.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });

    select_time2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"End time " + time_picker2.getCurrentHour() + " : " + time_picker2.getCurrentMinute(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            DBoperations db = new DBoperations(ctx);
            db.putInfo(db, time_picker1.getCurrentHour(), time_picker1.getCurrentMinute(), time_picker2.getCurrentHour(), time_picker2.getCurrentMinute(), 0, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Basically, I want the data just entered in the database from the TimePickerPopup class to show up in the ListView (i.e. refresh my list view). Presently it shows the new entered data after I close and then start my app.

Comment: Why not use a global method (singleton)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate of passing data to another activity. The issue here is that the code is tightly coupled so it must be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file inside `<fragment>` tag add this.

```
  android:tag="any_tag"
```

To get current object of a Fragment do this in java file (add this in your TimePickerPopup.java's onClick(View v) method)

```
MainActivityFragment2 ma2 =  (MainActivityFragment2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("any_tag");
ma2.populateTimeList();
```

Comment: It says cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Sorry you are using Fragment. so you will have to use getFragmentManager()

Comment: Now it says Inconvertible types

Comment: Try Fragment ma2 =  (MainActivityFragment2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("any_tag");